# the symplectic version of Gram-Schmidt process and one application of it.

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the following proposition:
[image]

> cf. McDuff and Salamon, *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*(second
>   edition), Corollary 2.4,page 40

One can assume $\omega_0 =\sum_i dx_i \wedge dy_i$. Here the theorem 2.3 is just the existence of a symplectic basis. What confused me is how to apply the Gram-Schmidt process to a symplectic linear space rather than an inner product space.

Answer (score 2):

You are also in an inner product space as well.

Since we know $\omega_t$ is a nondegenerate skew symmetric bilinear form (a symplectic form since we are not over a field of characteristic 2) then 
$\omega_t(u,v) = u^T A v$
for some skew symmetric full rank $A \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now the pullback condition is that 
$\Psi_t^\ast \omega_t(u,v) = \omega_t(\Psi_tu,\Psi_tv) = (\Psi_tu)^T A \Psi_tv = u^T (\Psi_t^T A \Psi_t) v = u^T J v = \omega_0(u,v)$

So the question amounts to if any $A$ described above is congruent to $J = \pmatrix{ 0 & -\mathbb{I} \\ \mathbb{I} & 0 }$, with the answer providing the $\Psi_t$. You also must show that such a family would vary smoothly along with $\omega_t$, but by fixing a basis this is very simple to prove.

As far as how Graham-Schmidt is used, think of how you would construct $\Psi_t$ knowing there exists a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n,f_1,\dots,f_n)$ which is a standard symplectic basis with respect to $\omega_t$. Immediately one could consider the change of basis matrix $K$ from the standard symplectic basis $(x_i,y_i)$ for $\omega_0$ and the $(e_i,f_i)$ mentioned above so that 
$K^{-1}AK = J$.

Now think of what condition is needed to turn the above similarity into congruency while preserving the requirements of a symplectic basis.

We want $K^{-1} = K^T$ so we want $K \in O(2n)$ which means its columns are an orthonormal basis, hence Graham-Schmidt (of course you also must show that Graham-Schmidt preserves the behavior of the basis elements with respect to $\omega_t$).

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to grasp your answer completely. Do you mean $\Psi_t$ should be $K$? Also, how to show that  the family $\Psi_t$ would vary smoothly?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, the proof for Thm 1.1 (bottom of pg. 3) in Ana Cannas Da Silva's "Lectures on Symplectic Topology" should be exactly what you're looking for. Also yes, for each $t$ the matrix $K$ will be $\Psi_t$.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to read this book!